# Find an inverse of a parametrization

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions

Let $\varphi\colon \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, \ \varphi(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix} u\\ v^3(1+v^3)+\sinh(u)\\ v^3(1-v^3) -\sinh(u)\end{pmatrix}$

I want to find and inverse of $\varphi$ on its image $\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

So be $\varphi(u,v)=(x,y,z)^t$. We then immediately see that for every $x\in\varphi(\mathbb{R}^2)$ we get a $u=x$.

We only miss a $v$ and therefore compute $y+z=2v^3$ and arrive at $\sqrt[3]{\frac{y+z}{2}}=v$.

The only problem is, $y+z$ must not be positive, so $v$ might not be defined.

Comment: What's wrong with taking cubic roots of negative numbers? $\sqrt[3]{-27}=-3$.

Comment: You need to check if $(x,y,z)^T$ is in the image of $\varphi(\mathbb R^2)$.

Comment: @Andrei I guess that is admissible, though in most of my books only roots of positive reals are treated. What do you mean by your second comment?

Comment: Given $x,y,z$, you have three equations with two unknowns. You might not have a solution that verifies all three equations.

Comment: But that is my requirement, I don't consider arbitrary $(x,y,z)^t\in\mathbb{R}^3$. I need this inverse to show, that $\varphi$ is homeomorphic into its image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously not every $(x,y,z)^T$ can be inverted. For example $(0,1,1)^T$. From your equations you would get $u=0$ and $v=1$, but $\varphi(0,1)=(0,2,0)^T$. That's because you get three equations with only two unknowns. So the way I would approach this problem is I choose only two of the components in the image of $\varphi$ in $\mathbb R^3$, and write the third one in terms of those two. Given $y$ and $z$, you calculated $2v^3=y+z$. Now plug this into the equation of $y$:
$$\frac{y+z}{2}\left(1+\frac{y+z}{2}\right)+\sinh x=y$$ or $$\sinh x=y-\frac{y+z}{2}\left(1+\frac{y+z}{2}\right)$$
Note that if you plug in this value in the equation for $z$ you get an identity. Then the image of $\varphi$ is the set$$\DeclareMathOperator\arcsinh{arcsinh}\begin{pmatrix}\arcsinh\left(y-\frac{y+z}{2}\left(1+\frac{y+z}{2}\right)\right)\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}$$
This yields $$\varphi^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}\arcsinh\left(y-\frac{y+z}{2}\left(1+\frac{y+z}{2}\right)\right)\\y\\z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$$ with $v=\sqrt[3]{\frac{y+z}{2}}$ and $u=\arcsinh\left(y-\frac{y+z}{2}\left(1+\frac{y+z}{2}\right)\right)$. If you want, you can further simplify $u$.

Comment: The point $(0,1,1)^t$ is not an element of $im(\varphi)$, it is not even in your form, where you expressed as $x,y,z$. I understand that I have not used all equations and obtained therefore a larger set of solutions than existing, is this correct?

Comment: Exactly. But if your $x,y,z$ are not in $im(\varphi)$, solving all three equations is impossible. If it is, solving two of them is enough. $im(\varphi)$ is a 2D surface in $\mathbb R^3$. So mapping a point that is not on this surface to coordinates of the surface does not make sense.

Comment: I think I got everything except the mapping of the point which is not on the surface. In your inverse function too, I can assign to $(0,1,1)^t$ coordinates. Your inverse function is defined on whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ if not restricted.

Comment: There is a constraint about $x$. Not every $x$ is allowed. $\varphi^-1$ is defined only on a subset of $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: I am just seeing that my "inverse" is only a one-sided inverse. Just to be sure, my solution is not correct, right?

Comment: Your solution is not complete. You missed saying that is defined on the image of $\varphi$, and specify what that is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82866/discussion-between-epsilondelta-and-andrei).